# [key:string]: any is missing in ChartOptions and Chart classes in highcharts.d.ts

Tags: angular, highcharts

Please refer below URL to understand my problem.

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/t4gmaxdv/)

The same chart am implementing in angular6  for the purpose i installed highcharts7.1.2 in my project. Once it is installed i got ts called "highcharts.d.ts". In this highcharts.d.ts file iam able to see ChartOptions and Chart classes. Here in both classes, what i observed is "`[key:string]:` any" is missed.

May i know why?????

Here my concern is i want to add my own properties/ callbacks in ChartOptions and Chart classes, but because of "`[key:string]:` any" missing in ChartOptions and Chart classes am unable to add.

Why i need to add is if you see in the above link the chart is implemented in javascript and where as iam implementing the same in angular i.e., typescript

In the line number 83 of the above URL code, the chart is allowing a dynamic property ("lbl") but typescript is not allowing the same because "`[key:string]:` any" missing.

This is my concern and will it be added in upcoming version ???????

```
chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
    height: '110%',
    events: {
      render: renderIcons,
      load: function() {
        let sum = 0;
        this.series.map((el) => {
          sum += el.data[0].y
        })

    chart = this;
    if (!chart.lbl) {   // Here lbl is dynamic object 
      chart.lbl = chart.renderer.label('', (this.chartWidth - 80) / 2, (this.plotHeight / 2) + 9)
        .attr({
          padding: 10,
          r: 10,
        })
        .css({
          color: '#000',
          fontSize: 20
        })
        .add();
    }

        chart.lbl
          .show()
          .attr({
            text: '<span style="font-size:.8em">Activity</span><br> <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:1.4em;color:#ff9933">' + sum+'</span>',
          });

   }
 }
}
```

Cannot find lbl property in Chart
Cannot find lbl property in ChartOptions

Comment: Since this is a question about wether the Highcharts will support a feature or not , rather than a code problem, I would suggest that you go directly to the source and ask in their GitHub repository here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple. You haven't declared the `chart` variable in callbacks. So this is the solution:

```
const chart = this; // instead of just: chart = this;
```

**Demo:**

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-attfdr